# How to build index for dynamic criteria in mongodb to improve performance

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, mongodb-query

I am building mongodb object and passing it to  findAll method of mongo repository.

How can I achieve faster performance by designing index around all these fields ?

```
val criteriaQuery = MongoDBObject.newBuilder
criteriaQuery += OrderNames.CLIENT_ID -> clientId
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(orderId))
  criteriaQuery += OrderNames.ORDER_ID -> orderId
if (StringUtils.isNoneBlank(customerEmail))
  criteriaQuery += OrderNames.CUSTOMER_EMAIL -> customerEmail
if (orderStartDate != null) {
  if (orderEndDate != null)
    criteriaQuery += OrderNames.ORDER_DATE -> MongoDBObject("$gte" -> orderStartDate, "$lte" -> orderEndDate)
  else
    criteriaQuery += OrderNames.ORDER_DATE -> MongoDBObject("$gte" -> orderStartDate)
}
else if(orderEndDate != null)
  criteriaQuery += OrderNames.ORDER_DATE -> MongoDBObject("$lte" -> orderEndDate)
return criteriaQuery.result
```

My question here is : 
 if i have a, b, c, d, e, f in criteria.
 And if i create index on (a, b, c, d, e, f)

Will it work for (a,c,d,e,f) , (a, c), (a, e, f), (a,c, f)) etc.
 I need to consider all of these ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create compound indexes that cover all query fields or you can relying on index intersection, but depends on the structure of collection and data.
For example, you can opt for sparse indexes to intersect with a unique index on CLIENT_ID

Comment: Can you please explain more how compound indexes will work here? There can me many possibilities as we have 7 8 fields in criteria.

Comment: For example
The following index on a collection:
{ x: 1, y: 1, z: 1 }
Can support queries that the following indexes support:
{ x: 1 }
{ x: 1, y: 1 }
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/

Comment: Thanks for responding.I had one more question, if i have x,y,z,a,b field in criteria. And i use indexing on only 3 x,y,z . Should that be fine ?

Comment: Yes. With the explain function on the find, you can check with the index how many documents are examined.